# Unable to delete inserted tag in a contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a simple editor which I can insert emoji(images) into.

I'm using DOCUMENT.execCommand to underake the insertion at the caret position. The insertion (which is a span tag) is successful, however, when I attempt to use the backspace to delete the characters including the span tag doesn't seem to work (i.e it gets to the span tag and it doesn't seem to delete, however, if you select the span directly and hit backspace then it deletes it.

I'm wondering whether I have implemented the DOCUMENT.execCommand correctly or whether I need to do something in order to get it to work.

Please see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/pt-inserting-emoji-into-contenteditable-m2b7vv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) as the example (If you place the cursor in the content editable div (either one) and hit the button then a span is inserted at the caret position).

I'm using Angular 7 as the framework.

Comment: It deletes when I hit the backspace

Comment: Which browser are you using, I'm on chrome on linux?

Comment: Chrome / Windows

Comment: The stack blitz is working

Comment: @chellappan are you using Chrome on windows as well ?

Comment: Alright I used Firefox and it appears to be working via Firefox on Linux.